# Is it possible to link Matlab with C# then with ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, matlab

I've an idea of a web application that I'll need in its core to implement some algorithms, my best choice is Matlab. I know that it is possible to interface Matlab with C#, also I know that it is possible to integrate c# with ASP.NET. So, Is it possible to interface matlab application with C# tools integrated inside .net web application? or is there another easier way to do integrate matlab with asp.net directly?

Comment: ASP.NET is a framework that requires and underlying language that is compatible with the CLR. Matlab is not compatible so you need to use C#

Comment: Yes.  All the call to Matlab would be through the c# application.  You wo8ld build a matlab dll and then use DllImport as the interface to the matlab code.

Comment: that's an improvement. So Is the idea of integrated all of that together going to work?, you know I might learn to do all of that then try and know the result, but it could save me a lot of time and effort to know the result in advance.

Comment: Thank you a lot !! . I think that's an answer not a comment. go for that man :) -jdweng